# How do I overcome Power BI single error message?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Trying to calculate previous years sales to date but my formula is returning the below message:

A single value for column 'TtlValue' in table 'Rebates with Splits' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Thank you

Here is my formula:
PYR = CALCULATE('Rebates with Splits'[TtlValue],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date]))

Current year formula works as shown below:
CYR = CALCULATE(SUM('Rebates with Splits'[TtlValue]),'Calendar'[Year]=Year(TODAY()))

Comment: The first formula, as the error message says, doesn’t have the `SUM` aggregator over the column in the first argument of `CALCULATE`.